# Method does not return random number from another method

Tags: c#, class

It was hard to find right title for this problem. I had little problem earlier with this dice game and I solved it, thanks for the guys in here Stackoverflow.

My game is 99% ready now, but somehow main program cannot return the dice numbers. This game is meant to break when player have three wins and that makes him a winner. That why there is round.

Console should look like this:

Name of player 1:

Name of player 2:

Round 1

"Player 1 name": 5 + 4 = 9

"Player 2 name": 1 + 2 = 3

Round 2 et cetera

And when player get three wins it is winner. I have also two other class but problem is with Dice so I do not attach the others here.

Class game

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using static System.Console;

namespace Dicegame
{
    static class Game
    {
        static int winline = 3;

        static int round = 1;

        public static void Aja()
        {
            Player p1 = new Player
            (
                Helpers.Syote.Merkkijono("Name of player 1: ")
            );
            Player p2 = new Player
            (
                Helpers.Syote.Merkkijono("Name of player 2: ")
            );

            Dice dice1 = new Dice();
            Dice dice2 = new Dice();


            for (int i = 1; p1.Points < winline | p1.Points < winline; i++)
            {
                int p1throw1 = dice1.Throw(), p1throw2 = dice2.Throw(), p1total = p1throw1 + p1throw2,
                    p2throw1 = dice1.Throw(), p2throw2 = dice2.Throw(), p2total = p2throw1 + p2throw2;

                round++;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Class Dice

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using static System.Random;

namespace Dicegame
{
    class Dice
    {
        static Random randomnumber = new Random();

        public int Count { get; set; }
        public int ThrowCount { get; set; }

        public Dice()
        {
            ThrowCount = 0;
        }




        public int Throw()
        {

            int Count = randomnumber.Next(1, 7);
            ThrowCount++;

            return Count;
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: In `Random.Next(lb, ub)` lb is inclusive, ub is exclusive. Your dice will always return values in the range [1, 5]. You should call `randomnumber.Next(1,7)`.

Comment: Suggestion for readability: declare one variable per statement, rather than 6 in a single statement.

Comment: also note the bug at `for (int i = 1; p1.Points < winline | p1.Points < winline; i++)`. You are repeating `p1` twice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You simply never actualise the points of P1 or P2.
Also you use a for loop where a simple while loop would work way better:

```
while(p1.Points < winline || p2.Points < winline)
{
    p1.AddPoints(dice1.Throw() + dice2.Throw());
    p2.AddPoints(dice1.Throw() + dice2.Throw());
    round++;
}
```

Comment: What is the point with AddPoints. I have only Points in my program. I got this error ```'Player' does not contain a definition for 'AddPoints' and no accessible extension method 'AddPoints' accepting a first argument of type 'Player' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)```

Comment: @masteroscar that is the problem, you have a lot of variables containing points, but you do nothing with them. You need to add them to `Player`, using `AddPoints` (that I just invented, you won't find it if you don't write it first) or a similar method.
Otherwise the conditions of the loop will never be met and you will be stuck in it forever: `p1.Points` and `p2.Points` will never be `>= winline` as you never modify them.

Comment: @alvinsantor Thanks. I'll try to solve that, thank you for tips.

Answer (score 0):

I post my solution of this I hope it helps someone in future. Commented all so it is easy to understand for beginners also.

```
do 
    {
        if (p1.Points == WINLINE || p2.Points == WINLINE)
        {
            break; // Break this loop when either one reach WINLINE points (3)
        }
        else
        {
                // Get random numbers for each throw between 1-6 and sum them together
            int p1throw1 = dice1.Throw(), p1throw2 = dice2.Throw(), p1total = p1throw1 + p1throw2,

                // Get random numbers for each throw between 1-6 and sum them together
                p2throw1 = dice1.Throw(), p2throw2 = dice2.Throw(), p2total = p2throw1 + p2throw2; 

            // Write round number which is how many times dice is thrown. Split with 2, because same dice is throwed two times in one round
            WriteLine($"Round {dice1.ThrowCount / 2}");

            // Write given player names and points of each throw and after all sum of those points
            WriteLine($"{p1.Name}: {p1throw1} + {p1throw2} = {p1total}");
            WriteLine($"{p2.Name}: {p2throw1} + {p2throw2} = {p2total}");

            // If player 1 get more points than player 2, add one point for player 1 and reset player 2 points
            if (p1total > p2total)
            {
                p1.Points++;
                p2.Points = 0;
            }

            // If player 2 get more points than player 1, add one point for player 2 and reset player 1 points
            else if (p1total < p2total)
            {
                p2.Points++;
                p1.Points = 0;
            }
                else // If something else (same points for both) do nothing
            {

        }
    }
}
while (true);

// When do loop broke print results of the game
if (p1.Points == WINLINE) // Print this if player 1 wins
{
    WriteLine($"Winner of the game is {p1.Name} and total rounds: {dice1.ThrowCount / 2}."); 
}
else if (p2.Points == WINLINE) // Print this if player 2 wins
{
    WriteLine($"Winner of the game is {p2.Name} and total rounds: {dice1.ThrowCount / 2}");

}
```